# Live stream with changeable overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

My point is to create a continuous video stream with overlay that will change depending on external events. Like YouTube radio channels, where the song name is changing depends on which track is currently playing.

I saw one of the interesting ways with using several ffmpeg instances and local streams for audio and video: one ffmpeg is playing audio to local port, and other combining it with video, taking the audio source from local audio stream. So I can change the audio during the stream without restarting it.

My question is, can I use the same scene for changing the overlay. Let's say I need to change the song name on the screen, is there any ways to do so with ffmpeg?

Comment: You might also want to look at avisynth+ http://avs-plus.net/

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at "streamlabs" or "obs", which are made specifically for those instances.

Comment: Thanks, Florian! But I'm using headless server, and OBS needs access to the GPU. It does not work even over VNC with installed linux GUI like Gnome or KDE. So i need to use only software that does not uses GPU for streaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## drawtext filter

If you just want to update some text on the screen the easiest method is to use the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter with the `textfile` and `reload` options.

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "drawtext=textfile=songs.txt:reload=1" output
```

`songs.txt` will be reloaded once per frame. Be sure to update it atomically, or it may be read partially, or even fail.

## overlay filter

If you prefer an image instead of text you have to manually select the image demuxer, loop the image, and replace `overlay.png` atomically whenever you want it to be updated.

```
ffmpeg -i input -f image2 -loop 1 -i overlay.png -filter_complex overlay output
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for.